# Connecting iPad to a Windows machine using PAN bluetooth

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, ipad

I am trying to setup a Bluetooth PAN between an iPad Wi-Fi (iOS 9) and a Windows 10 machine (I have tried with Windows 8 as well) but I can't establish a connection between the devices. The devices can see each other, but directly after pairing the iPad disappears from "Bluetooth Network Connections" (but still visible in the "Devices and printers" view)  on Windows and a popup appears on the iPad stating: "Windows-PC" is not supported.

Pairing a Windows tablet works fine.

I am beginning to suspect that it is simply not possible to create a PAN between an iOS device and a Windows machine. Can anyone confirm if this is true? Using Wi-Fi is not an option.

Comment: What is the model of the Bluetooth adapter on the PC?

Comment: The bluetooth device model is Realtek. I have tried downloading the latest drivers but it didn't solve the problem.